# Finding first word of specific td and copy else where

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have any code as i am having trouble finding anything related, but I have a set of tables that change depending on the data being pulled from the data base. I would like to be able to take the first word out of a specific td and insert it into the beginning of another... Is there anyway to do something like this any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you mark your td with an ID or an class?

Comment: of course there is? You could first take the exact td with $('yourTDid').html() and then extract the first word out by splitting string with string.split(" "); and take the first word in the returned array and insert it anywhere you want?

Comment: provide more information like html code or javascript and on what event you want to do this..be specific...

Comment: Ya i mark them with Id's

Comment: Is it really that terrible of a question that someone marks it down? I didn't know how to do something so i asked a question how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 3 steps:

**FIRST:** get your desired word from desired TD.

Here you can use ID or class or find() or anything to get to your TD. Than get its data with

> var string = $('yourTDid').html();

**SECOND:** get first word out with split()

```
var arr = string.split(" ");
var firstWord = arr[0]; // last word with arr.pop()
```

**THIRD:** insert this word to your desired element with

```
var oldvalue = $('desiredElementID').html(); 
var newvalue = firstWord + oldvalue;
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: @CWIEC Glad to help. If this question helped, you can mark it as correct so it might help others :) If you need any further help let me know

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your tables (for example using id or class).
Then you can get first td of first table and set td of second table value:

```
var text1 = $('#table1 td:eq(0)').text();
var text2 = $('#table2 td:eq(0)').text();
$('#table2 td:eq(0)').text(text1 + text2);
```

To get only first word use this code:

```
text1.split(" ")[0]
```

Comment: I need the first word of several td's in a table

Comment: I ended up using some one elses code, it sys i do not have enough points to upvote your answer, but if you upvote my question i should have enough then i can upvote your answer and comment???

Comment: I'm so sorry I'm still 2 point away from being able to upvote you maybe upvote one of my comments, I'm so so sorry I'll do the same for you whatever you do for me and more i feel terrible now, I just wanted you to have some points.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a start:

```
<html>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>row item 1</td>
<td>row item 2</td>
</ul>
</table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "td" ).each(function( index ) {
alert($(this).text().split(" ")[0]);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need the first word out of row item 1 and row item 2 and all the other td's in a specific table

Comment: You could use .each for that, I have edited the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

**i think this can help you :**

```
var id1="td1";//the id of the TD you want to get the word from
var id2="td2";//the id of the TD you want to put it into
var tmp =$('#'+id1).html();
    tmp = tmp.trim();
var word =tmp.substring(0,tmp.indexOf(' '));
$('#'+id2).html(word+' '+$('#'+id2).html());
```

Comment: I'm sorry it says object doesn't support property or method of 'trim'

Comment: then replace that line by 
tmp = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf(' '));